# Show options in secound select based on the first using data attributes

Tags: jquery

Here is my current code. What i want to happen is if the first selects value is ETS then only the options in the second select show if their data-game attribute is ETS elseif its ATS then only show ATS.

```js
var gameETS = $('#Departure').children("option[data-game=ETS]").clone();
var gameATS = $('#Departure').children("option[data-game=ATS]").clone();

$("#Game").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#Departure').children().remove();
  $('#Arrival').children().remove();
  if (value == "ETS") {
    $('#Departure').children().append(gameETS);
    $('#Arrival').children().append(gameETS);
  } else {
    $('#Departure').children().append(gameATS);
    $('#Arrival').children().append(gameATS);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="Game" name="Game" required>
  <option value="ETS">Euro Truck Simulator</option>
  <option value="ATS">American Truck Simulator</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="Departure" id="Departure" required>
  <option value="1" data-game="ETS">Cambridge</option>
  <option value="2" data-game="ATS">Las Vegas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The `append()` should be on parent.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your `append()` was to the `children()` of the `select` (ie. the `option` elements) instead of the `select` itself. Also note that you can make the logic much simpler by using `empty()` and joining the selectors. Try this:

```js
var $gameETS = $('#Departure option[data-game=ETS]').clone();
var $gameATS = $('#Departure option[data-game=ATS]').clone();

$("#Game").change(function() { 
    $('#Departure, #Arrival').empty().append($(this).val() == "ETS" ? $gameETS : $gameATS);
}).change(); // call change on load to set the values immediately
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="Game" name="Game" required>
  <option value="ETS">Euro Truck Simulator</option>
  <option value="ATS">American Truck Simulator</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="Departure" id="Departure" required>
  <option value="1" data-game="ETS">Cambridge</option>
  <option value="2" data-game="ATS">Las Vegas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Exactly what i want however doesn't seem to work in my code. Any reason it shouldn't?

Comment: None at all. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Have you put the code in a document.ready handler? eg `$(function() { /* code here */ });`

Comment: its inside a $(window).load(function(){

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look attached snippet.

Problem is in `append()` function usage. You have used like this `children().append()` that might be a reason for code not work.

```js
var gameETS = $('#Departure').children("option[data-game=ETS]").clone();
var gameATS = $('#Departure').children("option[data-game=ATS]").clone();
  
$("#Game").change(function() {

  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#Departure').children().remove();
  $('#Arrival').children().remove();
  
  if (value == "ETS") {
    $('#Departure').append(gameETS);
    $('#Arrival').children().append(gameETS);
  } else {
    $('#Departure').append(gameATS);
    $('#Arrival').children().append(gameATS);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="Game" name="Game" required>
  <option value="ETS">Euro Truck Simulator</option>
  <option value="ATS">American Truck Simulator</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="Departure" id="Departure" required>
  <option value="1" data-game="ETS">Cambridge</option>
  <option value="2" data-game="ATS">Las Vegas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What i want to happen is if the first selects
>   value is ETS then only the options in the second select show if their
>   data-game attribute is ETS elseif its ATS then only show ATS.

Also you can simply show the option which have `data-game` equal to `#Game option` value.

```
$("#Game").on('change',function() {
  $('select option:selected').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#Departure option[data-game=' +val+ ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```

```js
$("#Game").on('change',function() {
  $('select option:selected').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#Departure option[data-game=' +val+ ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="Game" name="Game" required>
  <option value="ETS">Euro Truck Simulator</option>
  <option value="ATS">American Truck Simulator</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="Departure" id="Departure" required>
  <option value="1" data-game="ETS">Cambridge</option>
  <option value="2" data-game="ATS">Las Vegas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I choose to put the data into an array and "generating" options in javascript. These option can be "auto-generated" using some other frameworks as `knockout` or `angularjs`.

Here is a solution with `jQuery` and `lodash`:

```js
var departures = [
  { value: 1, text: "Cambridge", game: "ETS" },
  { value: 2, text: "Las Vegas", game: "ATS" }
];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Game").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var selection = _.filter(departures, function(item) {
      return item.game == value;
    });
    
    $("#Departure").empty();
    
    _(selection).forEach(function(item) {
      $("#Departure").append('<option value="' + item.value +'" data-game="' + item.game +'">' + item.text +'</option>');
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="Game" name="Game" required>
    <option value="ETS">Euro Truck Simulator</option>
    <option value="ATS">American Truck Simulator</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="Departure" id="Departure" required>
    <option value="1" data-game="ETS">Cambridge</option>
    <option value="2" data-game="ATS">Las Vegas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$("#Game").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $('#Departure option').each(function() {
      if($(this).attr('data-game') == value) {
          $(this).show();
      } else {
          $(this).hide();
      }
  });
});
```